# Changing associations and switching to another assosiation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-4

if we have data in a table and table that has a has_and_belongs_to_many association and we want to change the association to has_many through and add a foreign key to that table and we also want the previous data of the table to be saved with foreign key what will we do?

Comment: How big are these tables? Are you able to have some temporary downtime while data syncs (which would be easier), or do you really need a "zero downtime" solution (which would be harder)?

Comment: just need a way to do ....time is not the problem

Comment: Actually, reading this again, I'm unclear what the problem is. Do you know how `has_and_belongs_to_many` works? There already **is** a join table. Unless you plan to rename that table, this is quite a straightforward change.

Comment: What are the names of the tables/models? What do you want the `has_many ... through: ...` to be? It helps if you show a bit of code, otherwise I have to invent to table/model names, which I think adds pointless confusion to my answer.

Comment: yes this is already a join table but i want to switch the association to has many through

Answer (score 1):

You would have to add a model to your application with the same name as your join table, or rename the join table with a migration.

What are the names of your models?

For example if you now have countries and companies. A country can have multiple companies and a company can have locations in multiple countries. You start with a model for Company and Country and a join table companies_countries.

You can create a model: CompaniesCountry and use it for the has_many :through

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :companies_countries
  has_many :countries, through: :companies_countries
end

class CompaniesCountry < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :companies
  has_many :countries
end
```

I think it would be nicer here to rename the join table to something more sensible like `company_locations` with a migrations and make a model for this instead. You could also store additional info like address or such on the model which you weren't able to do with the join table

The rails guides are a nice read on this as well: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Comment: will previous data will be saved ??

Comment: @hurab You're not changing any data. The join table already exists. The idea is to create an explicit reference to the join table, and create an associated model for it.

Comment: i cant understand the concept completely still confused

Comment: @hurab Your database already has three tables: `countries`, `companies` and `companies_countries`. This third table is necessary for a "has-and-belongs-to-many" association to exist, because that's the only way you can link all the different IDs together.

Comment: You never said **why** you want to switch the association to a `has_many ... through:...`, so I don't know what more you're confused about -- because I don't know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you provide some of your code @hurab in your question? so it might be easier to answer your case

Comment: actually its a question asked by my senior how how will you switch association from has-and-belong-to-many  to has-many :through and if you can switch ... will data placed in previous table will be saved or not?

Comment: ah ok, well in that case like @TomLord mentioned, the data will not change if you only add a new model class or change a relation in rails. Data can change if you make a migration or a rake task to update your database.